# SQLAlchemy query.filter_by returns nothing

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am in the process of learning SQLAlchemy and I am stuck on the below filter as it returns nothing for some reason.

```
search_term = Term.query.filter_by(term=term).first()
# I also tried the below as I know there is "toy" in the table.
search_term = Term.query.filter_by(term='toy').first()
```

I want to get it and then do `search_term.id` to get the ID that belongs to the term so I can then use it for another commit as part of the relationship.

```
#routes.py.
@search.route('/search/<term>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(term):
   search_term = Term.query.filter_by(term=term).first()
    if search_term:
        return 'term exists'

    search_term = Term(term=term)
    db.session.add(search_term)
    db.session.commit()

    search_term = Term.query.filter_by(term=term).first() # Returns nothing
    return f'test: {search_term}'
```

```
#Models.py
class Term(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    term = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    results = db.relationship('Results', backref='term', lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your filter_by expression. Can you try printing the id after the commit ? print(search_term.id) to make sure you got it in the database.

Comment: You can check if there is any data in by `Term.query.filter_by().all()` , and then use for loop to print all the terms.

Comment: Have you look inside db for query data existence?

Comment: I'm using SQLiteStudio to view the data in the database. The data is being entered through the commit but even when i do Term.query.all() I just see  [, , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Comment: @squidg
   print(term)
   obj = Term.query.all()
   print(f"count is {len(obj)}")
   for i in obj:
       print(i.term)
can you please add above code in your code and check the printed results.

Comment: @squidg You are using SQLite right? The issue occurred when you deployed your code or persist in the local system also?

Comment: count is 14 and then it lists the entries under term table. SQLite, local database

Comment: @squidg I think there might be issue somewhere else can you add all the relevant code for it.

Comment: It works if I do  return search_term.term or search_term.id for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but perhaps you need a **str** method in your model. Can you add something like

```
#Models.py
class Term(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    term = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    results = db.relationship('Results', backref='term', lazy='dynamic') 

    def __str__(self):
        return f"id: {self.id}"
```

Now you are returning `Term` without any representation